# Capturing Regex in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to grab the directory paths of GET requests and count them in Splunk using this capturing regex.

```
index=main sourcetype="access_combined_wcookie" | rex "(?i)\"GET /(?P<MYDIR>\w+)/" | timechart count by MYDIR
```

This sort of works. It grabs the name of the top level directories and sums them up by time as expected, except that it also displays HEAD requests as "NULL" or "OTHER."

The regex works as expected in both perl and Python (ie, it doesn't match on a HEAD request.) Anyone have an idea what I have to do to make Splunk stop reporting the stuff that I didn't capture to begin with? This behavior is really counter-intuitive.

Comment: Why not use field extractions (and filters on them)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you think Splunk is reporting stuff that you are not capturing to begin with is because you misunderstand how the *rex* command works.

*rex* does not filter out records. It adds the fields you extract to the events, if the regex exists. So in your case you are adding the MYDIR field to all events that contain GET, but you are still getting all events.

The sourcetype *access_combined_wcookie* is a pretrained source type in Splunk, which already has field extractions defined. It would be easier to use the already-extracted *method* field to limit your search to just the GETs.

```
index=main sourcetype="access_combined_wcookie" method=GET | rex "(?i)\"GET /(?P<MYDIR>\w+)/" | timechart count by MYDIR
```